# 'MYSQL' QueryException with message 'could not find driver'

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel-8, mysql-connector

I have this exception when I am trying to run my laravel 8 app :

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver (SQL: select
>
> - from information_schema.tables where table_schema = gestiondesservicespourccisdt and table_name = types_interventions and
>   table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Even I uncommented `extension=pdo_mysql` in `php.ini` file but i still can not found it at `PDO DRIVERS` when i check `phpinfo()`.

My configurations:

**`PHP 8.1 APACHE 2.4 MYSQL 8.0.29`**

```
APP_NAME="GestDSR"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:2u3gtLuxhkRS1ninoDLi9Spo/cH9EpXxzuuWdQg/trx=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://192.168.1.120

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=192.168.1.120
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=gestiondesservicespourccisdt
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=*******
```

**`Mysql user and host user: root  host: 192.168.1.120`**

**`PS: Its work good at local (127.0.0.1:8000) with php artisan serve`**

Answer (score -1):

Install Driver

using following command

`sudo apt-get install php8.1-mysql`

Then restart apache

`sudo systemctl restart`

Comment: i am using windows how can I do it